# Remove characters between ~~ sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My data is showing as "abcdefghijklmno~123~pqrstuvwzyz"

I want to remove this part ~123~

I want to get data as "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwzyz" after remove this part ~123~

Comment: Please clarify in your question that "123" could be any string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use substring operations here:

```sql
SELECT
    col,
    SUBSTRING(col, 1, CHARINDEX('~', col) - 1) +
    SUBSTRING(col, CHARINDEX('~', col, CHARINDEX('~', col) + 1) + 1, LEN(col)) AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

**Data:**

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 'abcdefghijklmno~123~pqrstuvwzyz' AS col
)
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: I've told you this before: learn the benefits of `CROSS APPLY (VALUES` :-)